# Rails 5.0.1, postgresql - aliased foreign keys and aliased tables with includes fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

tl;dr:

Database obfuscation of all tables and columns (including foreign keys) is causing a problem in obtaining a result in eager loading of associated models from postresql database using all rails queries. `includes`, `joins`, etc return errors rather than what they should.

begin:

I have a completely obfuscated database, every table and column is named using a 20 character random string of latin letters, including foreignkeys.
Typical migrations for has_many relations is:

```
class CreateModelOne < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :abcdfeghijklmnopqrst do |t|
      t.boolean :bcdfeghijklmnopqrstu, null: true
      t.float :cdfeghijklmnopqrstuv, null: true, default: 0
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateModelTwo < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :dfeghijklmnopqrstuvx do |t|
      t.date :feghijklmnopqrstuvxy, null: true
      t.time :eghijklmnopqrstuvxyz, null: true
      t.integer :ghijklmnopqrstuvxyza
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :dfeghijklmnopqrstuvx, :abcdfeghijklmnopqrst, column: :ghijklmnopqrstuvxyza
  end
end
```

In the model files I have aliased the relations:

```
class ModelTwo < ApplicationRecord
  alias_attribute :model_one_id, :ghijklmnopqrstuvxyza
end
```

when I want to eager load `ModelTwo`s associated with `ModelOne` I am trying to use the standard `includes` method:

```
@model_one = ModelOne.includes(:model_two).find(particular_model_one_id)
```

This is yielding the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `association' for nil:NilClass
    from /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:67:in `block in associated_records_by_owner'
    from /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/core.rb:349:in `init_with'
    from /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:69:in `instantiate'
    from /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in find_by_sql'
    from /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/result.rb:52:in `block in each'
    from /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/result.rb:52:in `each'
    from /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/result.rb:52:in `each'
    from /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:50:in `map'
    from /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:50:in `block in find_by_sql'
    from /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    from /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:49:in `find_by_sql'
    from /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bullet-5.5.1/lib/bullet/active_record5.rb:25:in `find_by_sql'
    from
```

This seems odd to me as running the queries individually works fine, as in:

```
ModelOne.find(particular_model_one_id)
```

returns the expected `ModelOne`, and

```
ModelTwo.where(model_one_id: particular_model_one_id)
```

returns the expected set of `ModelTwo`s. These produce the exact same `SELECT` queries to the DB as the `.includes` does.

Having a look at the object returned by `ModelOne.includes(:model_two)` returns the query I would expect, along with the message:

```
ModelOne Load (2.3ms)  SELECT "abcdfeghijklmnopqrst".* FROM "abcdfeghijklmnopqrst"
  ModelTwo Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "dfeghijklmnopqrstuvx".* FROM "dfeghijklmnopqrstuvx" WHERE "dfeghijklmnopqrstuvx"."ghijklmnopqrstuvxyza" IN (4, 1, 2, 3, 8, 5, 7, 6, 9, 10, 11, 14, 12, 13, 18, 15, 17, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 28, 23, 25, 24, 27, 26, 29, 30, 31, 34, 32, 33, 38, 35, 37, 36, 39, 40, 41, 42, 48, 43, 45, 44, 47, 46, 49, 50, 51, 52, 57, 53, 55, 54, 58, 56)
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

which I suppose also implies `(Object doesn't support #association)`.

Disclaimer:

I have read the related stackoverflow entries and the Rails issues on github, none of them appear address this particular issue, at least the attempts to implement the suggestions supplied within to do work.

I have changed my application of adding a `foreign_key` to a direct `references` in the migrations which yields the exact same behaviour.

I could, of course, write the proper queries to the database or not eager load the associated models but this seems inefficient wrt developer time as parsing the result from a hand written `JOIN` also needs to be handled and the (many more) real models have more than one column and more than one association.

Comment: I also told my duck all about it but she is being very quiet about the matter.

Comment: There is too long, could you add the TL;DR version on top of the question?

Answer (score 0):

So I made a module to hack around the issue, feel free to use in your horribly obfuscated DBs as you wish... prepare for hackiness:

```
module AliasedAttrsHelper
  def find_by_includes_aliased(id_col, id_match, *associations)
    # get foreign key column name
    class_name = self.to_s
    fk_column = class_name[0]
    class_name.split('').each_with_index do |char,i| 
      next if i == 0 
      fk_column += char.match(/[A-Z]/) ? "_#{char}" : char
    end
    fk_column += '_id'
    fk_column.downcase!
    # make id string and table name
    id_column = self.attribute_aliases[id_col.to_s]
    id_table = self.table_name
    # make the set of associations to query on
    associations.map! do |ass|
      name = ass.to_s.singularize.capitalize.constantize
      { class: name, table: name.table_name, fk: name.new.attribute_aliases[fk_column] }
    end
    # perform the composite query transaction
    klass = ""
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      klass = self.find_by_sql("SELECT c.* FROM #{id_table} AS c WHERE c.#{id_column} = '#{id_match}'")[0]
      associations.each do |ass|
        ass[:class].find_by_sql("SELECT b.* FROM #{ass[:table]} AS b JOIN #{id_table} as c ON c.id = b.#{ass[:fk]} WHERE c.#{id_column} = '#{id_match}'")
      end
    end
    klass
  end
end
```

Comment: the proviso being that your aliased foreign keys have the alias `model_name_id`, of course.